# Is there a way to save Strings after the program closes?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a banking system GUI and I've done well so far but I've run into quite the roadblock. I want to be able to log in, but only if you've previously created an account, but I'm not sure if it's even possible to run my create account class and save the information received for future use since the program will close. I assume it's not possible as I'd need a place to store the username and password for future use, such as a server or something, but I thought I'd ask to see if maybe there was something I could do with an array or something. (P.S. I know I shouldn't use .setLayout(null) but this is just a fun first solo coding project I'm trying to do and I don't understand what people say about it so I'll learn about it later)

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreateAccount{

   private JPanel panel;
   private JFrame frame;
   private JLabel username;
   private JLabel title;
   private JLabel passwordLabel;
   private JLabel confirmPasswordLabel;
   private JLabel alreadyLoggedIn;
   private JTextField usernameText;
   private JPasswordField passwordText;
   private JPasswordField confirmPasswordText;
   private JButton confirmButton;
   private JButton alreadyLoggedInButton;
   private JLabel failureLabel;

public CreateAccount()
{
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(panel);
    
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    Clicklistener click = new Clicklistener();
    
    title = new JLabel("Create New Account");
    title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    title.setBounds(150,10,200, 25);
    panel.add(title);
    
    username = new JLabel("New Username:");
    username.setBounds(40,50,100,25);;
    username.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
    panel.add(username);
    
    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Create Password:");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(30,90,150,25);
    passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
    confirmPasswordLabel = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");
    confirmPasswordLabel.setBounds(18,130,150,25);
    confirmPasswordLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
    panel.add(confirmPasswordLabel);
    
    alreadyLoggedIn = new JLabel("Already logged in?");
    alreadyLoggedIn.setBounds(28,225,200,25);
    panel.add(alreadyLoggedIn);
    
    usernameText = new JTextField();
    usernameText.setBounds(160,53,225,25);
    panel.add(usernameText);
    
    passwordText = new JPasswordField();
    passwordText.setBounds(160,93,225,25);
    panel.add(passwordText);
    
    confirmPasswordText = new JPasswordField();
    confirmPasswordText.setBounds(160,133,225,25);
    panel.add(confirmPasswordText);
    
    confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm Login");
    confirmButton.setBounds(205,190,125,25);
    confirmButton.addActionListener(click);
    panel.add(confirmButton);
    
    alreadyLoggedInButton = new JButton("Login Here");
    alreadyLoggedInButton.setBounds(140,225, 125,25);
    alreadyLoggedInButton.addActionListener(click);
    panel.add(alreadyLoggedInButton);
    
    failureLabel = new JLabel("");
    failureLabel.setBounds(175,160,400,25);
    panel.add(failureLabel);
    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
}

public String getUsername() {
    return usernameText.getText();
}

public String getPassword() {
    return passwordText.getText();
}

private class Clicklistener implements ActionListener
  {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        String confirmedPassword = confirmPasswordText.getText();
        
      if ((password.equals(confirmedPassword)) && (e.getSource() == confirmButton))
      {
        frame.dispose();
        //call Home Page
      }
      else if(!password.equals(confirmedPassword)) {
          failureLabel.setText("Passwords don't match. Try Again!");
      }
      
      if (e.getSource() == alreadyLoggedInButton)
      {
        frame.dispose();
        new Login();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

My Login class code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login {

   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel panel;
   private JLabel userLabel;
   private JTextField userText;
   private JLabel passwordLabel;
   private JPasswordField passwordText;
   private JButton button;
   private JLabel success;

public Login(){
    
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    userLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25); // x , y , width , height
    panel.add(userLabel);
    
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
    panel.add(userText);
    
    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
    passwordText = new JPasswordField();
    passwordText.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
    panel.add(passwordText);
    
    button = new JButton("Login");
    button.setBounds(135,80,80,25);
    button.addActionListener(new Clicklistener());
    panel.add(button);
    
    success = new JLabel("");
    success.setBounds(10,110,300,25);
    panel.add(success);
    success.setText("");
    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
}
private class Clicklistener implements ActionListener{
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if ((e.getSource() == button))
          {
            frame.dispose();
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any idea/tips on how id manage/implement that?

Comment: Since the program will close you loose all of your data. You should store the data in files or in database